# Oracle Virtual Box how to enable Direct3D

Tags: virtualbox, gaming

I have Oracles Virtual Box installed and wanted to run some games on them. As host I'm using Windows 7 and currently I have Windows XP installed in the guest. But when I try to run a game, then I get errors like Direct3D can not be activated.

Is this possible? And if yes, how do I have to configure the box to alow this? I have 3D support enabled, but aparently this seems not to be enough.

The particular game I want to run is IMO rather simple (Wimmebild), so I didn't really expect that it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have, Enable Hardware visualization on the Host PC, than boots the performance on virtual PC. and possible if you have that option and i cant be so sure too

plus enable 3D Acceleration. find the image below. hope that wil give you better performance

[image]

Comment: I'm running W7 as the host. Or do you mean in the VM?

Comment: Regardless of OS, in the BIOS there is a setting for Hardware Visualization, that gives boots for this type VM. if you don't have that option, no problem but Enable the 3D Acceleration in VM as shown in the image

Comment: Where do I find this dialog?

Comment: Right Click the XP VirtualPC on the list and select settings

Comment: I already have that 3d and 2d accelleration enabled and 128MB video memory assigned. But I get "Unable to init D3D" anyway.

Comment: Maybe give some more Video Memory and RAM Memory as well. this is the final try you can do. however everything is based on your host hardware!

Comment: 128MB is the max I can assign to video. I now assigned 2GB RAM but this also doesn't help.

Comment: I just ran dxdiag and it says that there is no 3D support.

Comment: I found the problem. Apparently when I installed the guest extension I didn't check the 3D support, so it was not available. It works now.